# Up voting a user again after the votes were reversed?

Tags: discussion, moderator, up-votes

I am presuming the up vote reversal from the up votes I gave was done independently of whether the answers were on my own questions or other questions. I am guilty of up voting too much on multiple users posts but not any user in particular.

Before I go behind a moderator's work I want to make sure not to undermine the moderators and re up vote answers on my questions that had been reversed?

Comment: I don't know (and don't need/want to) but they obviously didn't think it was little and that's what matters. It's better to start thinking of it as "important stuff" and not "little stuff".

Comment: @uhoh yes and not the place to vent.

Comment: by the way, please don't start re-upvoting your reversed votes *en mass*.

Comment: @uhoh I know now.

Comment: @uhoh that is vital information that should be included on the Electorate Badge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Up vote reversal is almost always done automatically, and isn't really in the hands of moderators at all. It can be done by SE staff, but they rarely do it. Using only upvotes isn't a problem, the thing that is looked out for is people who upvote only a particular user, or maybe 1-2 users, as they often are just trying to increase someone's reputation. I don't think it actually removes the upvotes, only the effect of the upvotes.

Comment: I'm sure in my case the vote was removed. @uhoh has answered a question I know I up voted and came back to it later to see the vote was reversed.